# What did Lucretia need rescued from (Girl Genius)

Tags: girl-genius

So I'm rereading the webcomic of Girl-Genius for another time and I'm at the [train depot](http://www.girlgeniusonline.com/comic.php?date=20150119#.ViL0ZyuAnVI) part of the storyline, and I wanted to ask a question.

What did Lucretia need rescued from in the following panel?  Not the locket, but she is talking about a previous event where she was supposed to "win" and even if she didn't there were a number of candidate rescue opportunities.  What was all that about?

[image]

Comment: This sentence is vague on purpose - we still don't know what was her state when she was stranded in Shadow World after Castle Heterodyne was damaged, but she didn't have human body, and couldn't eat cake.

Comment: Now it appears we know more about what was happening with her. She was rather stranded in the past, for a *very* long time.

Answer (score 3):

Lucretia, as the Other, was doing a marvelously successful job of conquering Europe with her slaver wasps; one presumes that's what was meant by "supposed to win". Maybe she even she believes she is still one of the good guys, whom she joined because the good guys always win.

Whatever happened to stop her, she vanished for eighteen years, until her machinations with the Knights of Jove and the Geisterdamen finally paid off and they managed to recall her into Agatha's body.

Presumably, she is rather displeased with her state of existence during that time, and at least partially blames her loved ones for not having come to her rescue.

Comment: It is always all about her.  Nothing that proves that like waiting to be rescued after starting and losing a war. Although this does imply that whatever happened to stop her, Bill wasn't part of it, or she didn't realize his part.

Comment: I've been thinking lots about the genre, that the wasps were coming in from high orbit and about the portal to mars.  When I read the first book, I really saw it as interplanetary war.  This makes me think Bill is on Mars, and that Zeetha is also from Mars - a "barsoom-esque" mars.  This also opens up that the technology from Lucretia was not her own, that the other was not all her, but that she was herself channeling something else - possibly a deposed despot spark on another planet who was trying to broadcast a signal that enabled inter-plantary conquest.... I know, its a lot of speculation.